# Poincare Formula in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $E_1,\dots,E_n$ be a finite sequence of measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^m$ of finite measure w.r.t.  $\mu$.
For all integer $p\in [1,n]$, we consider
$$
\sigma_p = \sum_{i_1<\dots <i_p} \mu(E_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap E_{i_p}) 
$$

The aim of the exercise is to prove the Poincaré Lemma and I took the exercise from page 37 of Georges, Exercices in Integration, 1984 available [here](http://library.lol/main/B6787788D6E1D0EB2401B9A0E58C23F5).

He defines for $A\subset \{1,\dots, n\}$:
$$
E_A = \bigcap_{i\in A} E_i, \quad E'_A =  E_A \setminus \bigcup_{i\notin A} E_i
$$
and he says that $E_A'$ are mutually disjoint.

I can't see this point. I made some computation using De Morgan property and I get

Comment: As written, I don’t think that they are disjoint. They definitely disjoint for disjoint $A,B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By De Morgan,

$$E_A' = E_A\cap (\cup_{i\not\in A} E_i)^c = E_A\cap (\cap_{i\not\in A}E_i^c)=(\cap_{i\in A}E_i)\cap(\cap_{i\not\in A}E_i^c)$$

In plain English, $E_A'$ is the set consisting of all elements that are in $E_i, i\in A$ but not in $E_j, j\not\in A$.

Now suppose $A\not=B$, and we may assume $i\in A\setminus B$, then we have $$E_A\subset E_i, E_B\subset E_i^c$$ $$E_A'\cap E_B'\subset E_i\cap E_i^c=\emptyset$$

By the way, the so-called Poincare lemma usually refers to [a result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma) in differential topology, and the book used "Poincare formula", which is just the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).